# Select Options Do Not Update Using jQuery on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, html-select

I made a site that updates select options when a race is loaded. When the user selects a race it brings up a series of select boxes. If a runner was previously assigned to a place then they will be loaded after the race loads. This works fine in every web browser I've tried (Firefox, Chrome, Safari), but not on the iPad, which is where it will mainly be used.

This is the Javascript code I have for the section that updates the places:

```
   $.post('getRunnerPlacements.php', {gender: race}, function(data) {
                var runners = data.split('*RUNNER*');
                var savedRunners = runners.length-1;
                for (var i=0;i<savedRunners;i++)
                {
                    var tempRunner = runners[i].split('*INFO*');
                    var place = tempRunner[2]-1;
                    var dd = $('#school'+place);
                    dd.val(tempRunner[3]);
                    loadRunners(place,race,tempRunner[0]);
                }
            });
```

...

```
function loadRunners(i,gender,place)
{
    var school = $('#school'+i+' option:selected').val();
    $.post('getRunners.php', {school:school,gender:gender}, function(data) {
        var runners = data.split('*RUNNER*');
        runners.pop();
        $.each(runners, function(key, value) {
            var temp = value.split('*INFO*');
            $('#runner'+i)
            .append($('<option>', { value : temp[0] })
            .text(temp[1]));
        });
        if (place != 'false')
            $('#runner'+(i)).val(place);
    });
}
```

I've tried non-jQuery approaches, but everything I've done leads to the same problem on the iPad. The school for placed runners will not load in the first select list, which causes the runner select list to show up blank. I have gotten it to work on occasion when I've put in an alert to test values, but this does not work every time. I also tried to delay execution of the loadRunners function using setTimeout, but that didn't help either. Any ideas would be much appreciated. You can see the live site at: invite.ymsrunning.com/results.php. Click on "Enter Results" and then select a race to see or set results.

Comment: Could you please share the data that is returned by the php script. And even better, since some HTML might help too, make a demo of the code over on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I follow everything the script is trying to do as it's hard without seeing what the two PHP ajax calls return.

But, I do see something odd that may or may not be related to the iPad issue.  You set the variable `place` like this:

```
var place = tempRunner[2]-1;
```

And then inside of loadRunners, you use it as:

```
if (place != 'false')
```

Those two lines are not compatible.   The first line appears to be treating `tempRunner[2]` as a number, but it looks to me like it's a string.  Subtracting a number from a string is not likely to do something useful.  If you mean for it to be a number, then you would probably want to do:

```
var place = parseInt(tempRunner[2], 10) - 1;
```

Then, if place is a number, the comparison in loadRunners to "false" doesn't make a lot of sense because you should be comparing to a number.